# Better to change uniforms or change program?

Tags: webgl

Using webgl I need to perform 3 passes to render my scene. Each pass runs the same geometry and shaders but has differing values for some uniforms and textures.

I seem to have two choices. Have a single "program" and set all of the uniforms and textures for each pass. Or have 3 "programs" each containing the same shaders, and set all the necessary uniforms/shaders once per program, and then just switch programs for each pass. This means that I will do one useProgram call per pass instead of *man* setUniform calls for each pass.

Is this second technique likely to be faster as it will avoid very many setuniform calls, or is changing the program very expensive? I've done some trials but with the very simple geometry I have at the moment I don't see any difference in performance because setup costs overwhelm any differences.

Is there any reason to prefer one technique over the other?

Comment: I believe switching programs will be faster but I'm not sure. In OpenGL ES 3.0 they added collections of uniforms, `uniform buffer objects`, so that you can set all uniforms in a block and then apply the entire block of uniforms in one call. My understanding is that some drivers have implemented that under the hood by just storing multiple programs internally, one for each block of uniforms. At the same time it probably depends on the driver which technique is faster. In general less calls into the driver is better.

Comment: Thanks, I should add that I've tried both and in my application there seems to be little measurable difference in the end. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just send different values via glUniform if the shader programs are the same.

Switching between programs is generally slower than change value of uniform.
Anyway Uber Shader Program (with list of uniforms like useLighting, useAlphaMap) in most cases aren't good.

@gman
We are talking about WebGL (GLES 2.0) where we don't have UBO. (uniform buffer object)

@top
Summing try to avoid rebinding shader programs (but it's not end of the world) and don't create one uber shader!

Comment: Right, that's what I'm doing now. Thank you for your post. The reason I asked was that I have the same shader but a fairly large number of textures to rebind for each pass. In practice it seems to make no difference which I do.

Answer (score 1):

When you have large amouts of textures to rebind, **texture atlasing** should be the fastest solution, so you don't need to rebind textures, don't need to rebind programs. Textures can be switched by modifying uniforms representing texCoord offsets.

Modifying such uniforms can be optimized even further:

You should consider moving frequently modified uniforms to attributes. Usualy their data source are provided using attribPointers but you can also use constant values when they are disabled. Instead of unformXXX() use attribXXX() functions to specify their constant values.

I think best example is light position. Normaly you'd have to specify uniform values for it every time light position changes **to ALL programs** that make use of it. In contrast, when using 'attributed' uniforms you can specify attribute value **once globaly** when your light moves.

-pros:
This method is best suited when you have many programs which would like to share uniforms, as we know we can't use uniform buffers in WebGL, it seams to be the only reasonable solution.

-cons:

Of course available size of such 'attributed' uniforms will be much smaller than using regular uniforms, but it still can speed things up a lot if you do it to some part of your uniforms.